# How can I get around the lack of LINES STARTING BY support in mysqlimport?

Tags: mysql, optimization, mysqlimport

I want to import data from multiple text files into MySQL. I was thinking of using `mysqlimport`. However, my lines begin with some prefix, and it turns out `mysqlimport` [does not support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) the `LINES STARTING BY` clause of `LOAD DATA`; apparently this is a [WONTFIX bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=1628).

So, what do I do? Can I do better than pipe everything through `cut` to kill the prefix?

Answer (score 1):

I'm working several years now with MySQL and I must admit, I didn't know of mysqlimport :)

Since you seem to insist on using mysqlimport, you want to stay on command line / console, I guess?

Then you can also just tell MySQL to execute one command without entering interactive mode.

```
mysql -uYourUserName -pYourPassword -hYourHost DB_Name -e "LOAD DATA INFILE..."
```